# Jupyter Notebook trying to make a scatterplot

Tags: python

`test = df_Resturant.groupby('cuisine_type') test['stars'].value_counts()`
Doing so basically shows cuisine types underneath example(Chinese, Thai, Korean, Italian, Mexican) with stars to the right (this dataset is star reviews) example(1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 4, 4.5, 5) and to the right of the star reviews is the total amount of stars
`sns.scatterplot(data=test['stars'].value_counts(), x= test.groups.keys(), y=test['stars'])`
but it doesn't seem to plot correctly?
I apologize. This is my first time using stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

Part of the challenge is that you are really trying to represent three data dimensions with your scatter plot:

1. cuisine type
2. star rating
3. count

Try this:

```
sizes = df.groupby(["cuisine_type", "stars"]).size().reset_index(name='counts')
sns.scatterplot(x='stars', y='cuisine_type', size='counts', data=sizes)
```

If you want the y-axis to be the `value_counts`, simply set `y='counts'` and use something like `hue='cuisine_type'` to indicate cuisine type since dot size is not relevant for categorical variables.

Output:

[image: output plot]

Comment: the desired plot would be
the x axis showing star ratings (1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3 ...)
the y axis showing the different cuisine types
and the value count of the cuisine types based on the star counts
i'd love to show an image and such but i don't have enough reputation either haha..
the dataset is from yelp
basically i'm only getting restaurant yelp reviews
and i want to compare the cuisine type with the stars on a scatterplot

Comment: Can you please provide a minimal reproducible example so I can load the dataset?

Comment: data = {'cuisine_type':  ['Chinese', 'Italian','Mexican','Chinese','Chinese'],
        'stars': ['1', '1','2.5','1.5','1']}
data = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['cuisine_type','stars'])
data.head().value_counts()

Comment: Thanks, taking a look now